# can you give me an example of not serializable data?

Tags: serialization

I'm studying some basic informatic concepts, so this could be a very noob question. I've understood what Serialization is, and what is used for. What I'm trying to understand is if all objects are serializable. You can download from the Internet any file you like: to do that all the files have to be serializable, right?
Is there a file or an object that you cannot serialize?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Some objects contain references to system resources such as file descriptors. You may still serialize such objects because file descriptor is a 32/64 bit number. But if you deserialize it in another process/computer, it won't have any meaning because system resources are valid only in process where they were acquired. So, *logically* not all objects are serializable.